# API receiving undefined data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I'm new to JS and react, but I'm attempting to pass a string to my API which will then run analysis on said string and pass back a sentiment score. However when I pass the data, whilst in my API's console the string appears in the 'body', the API states that the 'Description' is undefined, causing the API to throw an error.

api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('body is:', req.body);
    const {description} = req.body;
    console.log('Description is:', description);

    var Analyzer = require('natural').SentimentAnalyzer;
    var stemmer = require('natural').PorterStemmer;
    var analyzer = new Analyzer("English", stemmer, "afinn");
    const sentiment = analyzer.getSentiment(description.split(' '));

    console.log('Sentiment is:', sentiment);

    res.json(JSON.stringify({sentiment}))
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

diary.js containing the post function and the api call

```
async function makePostRequest (diaryText) {

  let payload = { Description: diaryText };

  let res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/', payload);

  let data = res.data;
  console.log("This is the data returned in the post function:",data);
}

makePostRequest("testText").then(response => {
  console.log("Data returned from the function call:", response);
}).then(error => {
  console.error(error.response.data);
});
```

This is the output in the console when the above code is executed:

```
body is: { Description: 'testText' }
Description is: undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at /Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/api.js:14:54
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (/Users/ddavies/Desktop/Desktop Storage/programming/MSc_App/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object key is sensitive, `Description` =/= `description`

```
const {Description} = req.body;
```